# Insert a new record to table in GUI java

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on the insertion a new data to mysql database. I got an error says that

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '')' at
 line 1
```

Can anybody show me what is wrong with my code? Here is my code:

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String queryString = "";
        String queryString2 = "";
        String outputString = "";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dealer", "root", "admin");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            String driverID = driverIdTextField.getText();
            String firstName = firstNameTextField.getText();
            String lastName = lastNameTextField.getText();
            String address = addressTextField.getText();
            String phone = phoneTextField.getText();
            String license = licenseTextField.getText();
            String brand = brandTextField.getText();
            String model = modelTextField.getText();
            String year = yearTextField.getText();
            String selectItem = (String) carStatus.getSelectedItem();

            queryString = "insert into person values ('" + (driverID) + "' + '" + (firstName) + "' +  '" + (lastName) + "' + '" + (address) 
                + "' + '" + (phone) + ")";
            queryString2 = "insert into cars values ('" + (license) + "' + '" + (brand) + "' + '" + (model) + "' + '" + (year)
                + "' + '" + (selectItem) + ")";

            statement.executeUpdate(queryString);
            statement.executeUpdate(queryString2);
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqlException){
                sqlException.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( ClassNotFoundException x ) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( InstantiationException x ) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException x ) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is my tables. I have two tables

```
create table person
( driverID int unsigned not null primary key,
  firstName char(20) not null,
  lastName char(20) not null,
  address char(30) not null,
  phone int unsigned
);

create table cars
( license char(10) not null primary key,
  brand char(20) not null,
  model char(20) not null,
  year date,
  status char(10) not null
);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'd recommend a) printing out those String objects you use as queries, which will make any errors in syntax more readable b) use a PreparedStatement to do the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing commas in your INSERT statements (you've used plus signs instead)...

```
queryString = "insert into person values ('" + (driverID) + "', '" + (firstName) + "',  '" + (lastName) + "', '" + (address) 
            + "', '" + (phone) + "')";
```

(I think you were also missing a close quote on that line)